# Pointers and constants in C

Tags: c

What's the difference between the below four C statements

```
    const int* variable;
    int const* variable;
    int* const variable; 
    const int* const* variable;
```

P.S: It'd be great can somebody explain with examples !

Tried understanding the pointer concepts in C but couldn't understand the below variants.